# What is the calculus-theoretic formula to calculate the homotopy class/degree of a map $T^2\to S^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I know by Hopf classification theorem that $[T^2;S^2]$(torus to sphere) are classified by the integral cohomology group $H^2(T^2;\mathbb{Z})\approx\mathbb{Z}$. Also I understand that in general, given any continuous map $\phi:T^2\to S^2$, we can first obtain a cellular approximation $\tilde{\phi}$ of $\phi$, then the problem reduces to simple cellular decompositions and calculations of degrees of maps on cells.

The problem is that the above procedure seems very hard to be programmed into a computer. I'm wondering, if I only care about smooth maps, is there a calculus-theoretic formula of doing it? Let's, say  use the following notations, 
$$\phi:(z_1, z_2)\mapsto(u(z_1,z_2),v(z_1,z_2),w(z_1,z_2)),$$
where $(z_1, z_2)=(\exp(ix_1), \exp(ix_2)), x_1,x_2\in[0,2\pi)$ and $u^2+v^2+w^2=1$; or any other notation you find more convenient.

Comment: Integrate the pullback of the surface form.
$$4\pi\deg\phi=\int_{T^2}\phi^*(u\,dv\wedge dw+w\,du\wedge dv+v\,dw\wedge du)$$

Comment: @user8268, thank you!

Comment: @user8268: Sorry. I was typing my long-winded answer as you put this up.

Comment: @TedShifrin: it's me who's guilty of answering with a comment (because I was too lazy with providing details) (and I know that comments don't pop up while you're writing an answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for calculus, so it's very simple. You want to take a $2$-form that generates $H^2(S^2)$, pull it back by your mapping, and integrate over the torus. So, if you had the mapping in spherical coordinates, most conveniently, say 
$$f(e^{2\pi i s},e^{2\pi i t}) = (\phi(s,t),\theta(s,t)),$$
then you would pull back $\frac1{4\pi}\sin\phi d\phi d\theta$, which is the area $2$-form, integrate $ds\,dt$ over $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and that would be your degree.

(If your mapping is, as you indicated, given in cartesian coordinates, then just pull back $\frac1{4\pi}(x dy\wedge dz + y dz\wedge dx + z dx\wedge dy)$ and integrate.)

If you need further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, let me think about it tomorrow, just had a tiring day.

Comment: Ok, let me try to fill in the details and I hope you can check if the reasoning is correct, I'm still taking my baby steps in topology so please bear with me if there's too much triviality: since 3-forms on 2-manifold must be 0, the area 2-form must be closed, and it can't be exact by Stokes theorem,  also $H^2(S^2)$ has rank 1, so the area 2-form is a generator. To obtain the integration formula, I guess we are passing from de Rham cohomology to singular cohomology by the isomorphism given by de Rham theorem?

Comment: And how to prove the homotopy classes are uniquely determined by the induced homomorphsims on $H^2$? I guess this is textbook stuff, so a reference would be good enough.

Comment: We're using the fact that degree of a continuous (smooth) map $f\colon M\to N$ between compact, oriented $n$-manifolds is the induced map $f^*: H^n(N)\to H^n(M)$. See also the Degree Theorem in Guillemin & Pollack. There you can also find a proof (in exercises) of Hopf's Theorem that two maps $M\to S^n$ are homotopic iff they have the same degree ($M$ as above).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out:)

Comment: You're welcome. This is quite beautiful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to the Gauss linking number, one of the first examples of a topological invariant given by an integral. You'll find an extensive historical discussion in "Orbits of Asteroids, a Braid, and the First Link Invariant", by Moritz Epple, *Mathematical Intelligencer* v.20 no. 1 (1998) p.45-52, and in "Gauss' Linking Number Revisited", by Renzo Ricca and Bernardo Nipoti, *Journal of Knot Theory and Its Ramifications*, v.20 no.10 (2011) p.1325-1343, including Gauss's original integral formula for what you seek.

The Wikipedia article on Linking Number gives the Gauss formula in slightly more modern form: [Linking Number: Gauss's integral definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Gauss.27s_integral_definition).

To relate this to your question, you have two parameters $z_1$ and $z_2$ each ranging over a unit circle. Let $\gamma_1(z_1)$ and $\gamma_2(z_2)$ be embeddings of these circles into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume that the embeddings are disjoint. So we have a pair of loops. Then $\phi(z_1,z_2)=\gamma_1(z_1)-\gamma_2(z_2)$ is a mapping of the torus into $\mathbb{R}^3\smallsetminus\{0\}$, which immediately gives us a mapping into $\mathbb{S}^2$, and its index is the Gauss linking number of the two loops.

Your case is a little more general, since your $\phi$ is any smooth map from $\mathbb{T}^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$. The formula given in the other posted answer shows how Gauss's formula generalizes to this case.

Here's a link to one of the historical articles: [Gauss' Linking Number Revisited](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ricca.pdf)